# I am a beginner in OOP in python and am getting "not enough values to unpack" in my code

Tags: python

```
class Fruits:
    def __init__(self,name,colour,taste,hasColour): 
        self.name = name
        self.colour = colour
        self.taste = taste
        self.hasColour = hasColour
    def hasAlternateColour(self):
        return self.hasColour

if __name__== "__main__":
    fruitList = []
    print("Enter name, colour, taste of the fruit")
    for itr in range(2):
        name,colour,taste = input().split()
        hasColour = input("Does it have another colour")
        fruitList.append(Fruits(name,colour,taste,hasColour))

    for fruit in fruitList:   
        print(fruit.name,fruit.colour,fruit.taste,fruit.hasAlternateColour(),sep="\t")
```

Ouput:

```
Enter name, colour, taste of the fruit
apple red sweet
Does it have another colour yes
```

Error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "E:/Programs/pyoop/Fruitclass.py", line 15, in <module>
>     name,colour,taste = input().split() ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)
```

Comment: Did you ever just press `enter/return` before typing in the answers for the questions ?

Comment: sorry I am new to stack overflow

Comment: The comment wasn't about Stackoverflow. It looks like you press "Enter" on your keyboard before you type in the values.

Comment: Try adding a print statement to see what the split gives you `print(input().split())` - you'll be able to see what's wrong.

Comment: yes but I had already typed all the three values before pressing enter

Comment: Do `data = input()` then `print(data)` then `name, colour, taste = data.split()`. Do you see your input being printed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you've pressed `Enter` on the second iteration of the loop just because program stucks without any message. You can replace `print` with `input` and put it inside the loop, thus program will always stops with the message: `Enter name, colour, taste of the fruit`:

```
if __name__== "__main__":
    fruitList = []
    for itr in range(2):
        name, colour, taste = input("Enter name, colour, taste of the fruit ").split()
        hasColour = input("Does it have another colour ")
        fruitList.append(Fruits(name, colour, taste, hasColour))
```

Comment: Good guess. That might be the reason.

Comment: Alternative: We could get rid of the `print` and use `name,colour,taste = input('Enter name, colour, taste of the fruit').split()`.

Comment: yes it's correct. thank you so much, it actually did not come to my mind that the print statement for name, colour and taste will only work once

Comment: @Matthias Agreed. Answer improved